# Ruby comparing dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I would like to do is to know if a user has been created in the system in the last 10 second.
so i would  do:

```
  def new_user
    if(DateTime.now - User.created_at < 10)
      return true
    else 
      return false 
    end
  end
```

IT is just an idea , how can i do it correctly?
thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def new?
    created_at > 10.seconds.ago
  end
end

# Example:
user = User.create!
user.new?
#=> true

sleep 11
user.new?
#=> false
```

(Presuming your `User` class is an `ActiveRecord` model.)

Answer (score 3):

```
User.created_at > 10.seconds.ago
```